# How to stop Visual Studio from resetting view layout upon each start/run?

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio

Every time I start (run) my program, Visual Studio resets* the view layout. And then it keeps the reset upon termination.

How can I avoid this?

I find this particularly problematic with multiple monitors where the windows in the view layout are not locked to the screen divider position and are manually set there.

(Using Visual Studio 2010 Express.)

EDIT: To replicate, make sure you have more the source code window is split into at least two (showing two or more source files).

EDIT 2: This has happened for as long as I can remember, for all Visual Studio editions I have used. It did not just start to happen.

EDIT 3: I have no addins installed.

*EDIT 4: By "resets" the view layout, I mean it re-adjusts all the currently opened views, just a bit. No major issue really, other than it it pushes the edge of one view from the edge of a multiple monitor to beyond it (meaning my source how spans to the next monitor), requiring manual readjustment.

Comment: That shouldn't happen.  There's no way we can offer a suggestion without more information.

Comment: But, it does happen. I'm not sure what else to explain. I investigated it again, just now, and it happens. Maybe I'll post screenshots to show.

Comment: It doesn't matter if you prove that it's happening; I'm not saying it's not happening, I'm just saying there's nothing we will be able to do to help, unfortunately.  Try disabling any addins you have.  Try re-installing VS.  That's all I can offer you.  Has it just started happening (i.e. did it work correctly before and suddenly it doesn't now)?

Comment: Why are you still using 2010 express?  Install 2013 community and never look back.  Jeez, if I hated myself that much, I'd need therapy.

Comment: @Will, please no questions about why I am still using older software, and trust there are reasons. I do appreciate suggesting newer software however it does not solve my issues.

Comment: @roryap, this has always happened as far back as I can remember. It just never bothered me before until it starts moving my manually set window panes to match the screen edges in my multiple monitor setup. From memory, Visual Studio (all versions I have used) have always done this.

Comment: It would solve your issue. But if you want to still beat yourself over the head with that brick, it's your head. Forgive me if I don't trust your reasons are as valid as you believe them to be.  Good luck.

Comment: @Will, it would solve this issue... maybe. But it would introduce new incompatibility issues with my current project that are another conversation entirely. To make you feel better, I did try to use updated software. This issue above is just a simply issue and should have a simple fix. It is not a big deal.

Comment: Ah, technical debt. You need to pay that off sometime :)